# Is there any way to remove the upper left corner gap in Microsoft Edge

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

I recently switched to Microsoft Edge from Chrome and my only problem is that small gap on the upper left corner of the toolbar, after hiding the vertical tabs button.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSZE1.jpg)

I want to be able to click my first pinned tab even with my eyes closed (don't ask), so it has to be on the leftmost side of the toolbar like it is in Chrome. I won't go back to Chrome since switching tabs is slower and I get black tabs if I use it for days without restarting, sometimes even before that. Restarting means reloading all those tabs and logging in to every vendor again, finding where I left on Google Sheets etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that gap in Edge. It's by design and we can't change it.

The only thing we can do is providing advice about this to Edge team by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge. The Edge team will check the feedbacks and improve the products continuously.